# PUT trouble in rest api

Tags: php, json, rest, yii

I am using the rest API in Yii. I want to implement an update function using `PUT`, but it doesn't work and always returns an unchanged result from the database.

```
public function actionUpdate(){    
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    echo $json;
    $put_vars = CJSON::decode($json,true);  //true means use associative array
    echo count($put_vars);
    ...
```

The above code is my function. I detected the problem in line  $put_vars = CJSON::decode($json,true); 
because $json is not empty after submitting key/value pairs, but after decoding, the data becomes empty.

You may try in some rest client and see results by yourself:
http://www.taxitaxi.kz/dispatcher/index.php/api/test/1

key/value: rating/8

echo of $json gives following response:

string(232) "------WebKitFormBoundarypsSvnRl0DUwJooRP Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rating"

8 ------WebKitFormBoundarypsSvnRl0DUwJooRP Content-Disposition: form-data; name="date"

333 ------WebKitFormBoundarypsSvnRl0DUwJooRP--

key/value pairs was: rating/8, date/333

Is it parceble json response?

Comment: Sorry I might be wrong, but can't you just use `json_decode`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I've never used `CJSON::decode`, but why can't you simply use `json_decode`?

Comment: Is the response suppose to be JSON? Putting the count after would break that.

Comment: I didn't paste all functions. Be sure that after this one I have funcions with foreach looping and sending response function. The issue is in this recieving function for sure

Comment: with json_decode result the same (empty). CJSON::decode is optimized method from yii

Comment: You said that the $json is not empty though, right? So that means that the problem is most certainly with `CJSON::decode($json,true)`. You could try to `var_dump` $put_vars.

Comment: I tried it. The response is NULL

Comment: It doesn't look like you are sending JSON to the server, which would make it hard to parse it. Check out http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getRestParams-detail and see if you get the values you are looking for from this method.

Comment: oh thanks Willem. I used Postman plugin for a testing and just filled key/value fields. Now I paste json array into body request and function becomes wordking. Thanks all, and for such stupid thing :)

Answer (score 0):

I have very similar code in a live site and I use:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $_PUT);
```

Then `$_PUT` is an array of your PUT data just like $_GET or $_POST would be. You can then do whatever you like with it.